# tkinter gui hangups/freezes after destroy() on macOS

Tags: python, tkinter, freeze

i'm working on a little python script, and having trouble with the tkinter destroy() function and macos. my window is set up like this:

```
class TextBox():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        text_box = tk.Text(self.root, ...)

    def quit_window(self):
        self.root.destroy()
```

calling `self.quit_window()` from within the class works as expected, but creating an instance of `TextBox()` and calling the quit function like this:

```
box = TextBox()
box.quit_window()
```

makes the window unresponsive with the mac loading wheel spinning when focused. am i making a weird mistake? i've seen threads about some versions of tkinter having trouble with macos, but using different python installs had no effect. thanks!

Comment: IIRC, the "trouble" was with the version of tcl/tk that comes with macOS. Newer versions of Python  therefore use a bundled tcl/tk. See [here](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) for the full story.

Comment: Question; where are you starting your `mainloop`?

Comment: @RolandSmith last line in the init! currently trying more python installs to see if that will nip this away.

Comment: Not saying that it is relevant, but the most common way to write a `tkinter` program as a class seems to be to make it a subclass of `tk.Tk`.

Comment: @RolandSmith thanks! i did a bit of revising in this. fyi, i found a solution - implementing an `after()` delay of 1ms allowed the function to be called with an instance of the class. my script is super simple, so this must just be due to how i've chosen to initialize my objects.