# tkinter.filedialog calling twice cause crashing on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter

Here below is my code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
path_1 = filedialog.askdirectory()
path_2 = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

I am trying to call `filedialog.askdirectory()` multiple times. I can run the above code in Windows without any problem. But when I do this in macOS, Python crashes once I call the function 2nd time (it is fine if just call once). The crash message is as follows:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Actually, my original implementation is as below (since I found most people do like this):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path_1 = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root)
path_2 = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root)
root.destroy()
```

This implementation way does not cause any crashes in macOS. But there is a bug that, the `root` cannot be destroyed properly. The problem is as described in this question: [tkinter gui hangups/freezes after destroy() on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465735/tkinter-gui-hangups-freezes-after-destroy-on-macos). There will be an unresponsive window named 'Tk' left after `root.destroy()`. Therefore, I try to use `filedialog.askdirectory()` directly without `root`. Both the 2 ways above work fine in Windows, but not in macOS.

Here is some detail of my macOS env:

- Python 3.10.4
- tkinter 8.6
- macOS 12.3.1
- arm64 M1

How should I code to call `filedialog.askdirectory()` multi times on macOS, without trigger the above errors?

Comment: I have a full crash report, but it is too long, and I am not sure if it is secure to post here. I may upload it if there is a need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have kind of solved the problem after many tries. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path_1 = filedialog.askdirectory()
path_2 = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

The above code does not generate any crashes or unresponsive windows on macOS. I found that there is no need to do `root.destroy()`. And, not passing `root` to `filedialog.askdirectory()` as `parent` argument, can prevent `Tk` window from showing behind the file dialog window. Hope this solution can help those who are dealing with the same problem as mine.

But still, I do not quite understand why I can call `filedialog.askdirectory()` directly on Windows, for multi times without any problem; but on macOS, I must first call `tk.Tk()` and `withdraw()` to prevent crashes. Please let me know if anyone knows the answer.